# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/members/js/bootstrap.min.js"):(Missing Asset files)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using bootstrap2 and set up tabs

```
  <ul class= "nav nav-tabs">
   <li class="active"><a href="#menu1" data-toggle="tab">疑問リスト</a></li>
   <li class=""><a href="#menu2" data-toggle="tab">フォロー中の投稿</a></li>
   <li class=""><a href="#menu3" data-toggle="tab">ユーザーの投稿</a></li>  
  </ul>
```

on show.html.erb(members). It works on the local but doesn't work on the remote(heroku).

And I checked logs,doing heroku logs and got some error messages. I have no idea how to solve this.Could you help me?

☆error messages

```
 ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/members/js/bootstrap.min.js"):
 ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/members/js/bootstrap.min.js"):
```

☆show.html.erb(members_controller)

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/members/css/bootstrap.min.css"):

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the Javascript file import to this:

```
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and the CSS link to this:

```
<link href="/assets/bootstrap.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
```

### On the assets handling in Rails >= 3.x

In Rails 3.x and 4.x all the assets must be placed in the `app/assets` directory. Javascript files will go into the `javascripts` folder, CSS file into the `stylesheets` folder and the images into the `images` folder. You can also add more folder to differentiate other asset types.

When in production, all assets will be available under the global folder `/assets` with no asset type distinction.

If you have correctly placed the assets, the best way to load them into your pages is using the absolute reference to them. Eg.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "/assets/bootstrap.min" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/bootstrap.min" %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but the same error occurred again. ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/bootstrap.min.js"):

Comment: Be sure to put the `bootstrap.min.js` file under the `app/assets/javascripts` directory.

Comment: Mr.marzapower, thank you very much!! The error has been removed.

Comment: The error about js file has been removed but still, css error remains.ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/members/css/bootstrap.min.css"): I have no idea..

Comment: Thank you. You mean I have to put "bootstrap.min.css" on the assets folder(I have done.)? Or I have to write some codes on "bootstrap.min.js"?

Comment: Mr.marzapower, thank you very much!! Now, all the errors of heroku logs were removed.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed according to instructions: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#a-ruby-on-rails and use default template: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template then you just need to remove the following lines from template:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```